# getSaveFileName , getOpenFileName shows me the file to save or open, but cannot save the file or open the file in python QT

Tags: python, qt, csv

```
1.fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File",
                        "F:/python/bc_new_latest/bcForecasting.csv",
                        "Excel (*.csv *.xls )");

2.fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save",
                        "F:/python/bc_new_latest/bcForecasting.csv",
                        "Excel (*.csv *.xls )");
```

The above 2 codes shows me file dialog's to open me the file in specified location or save the file. But can not open the file or save the file in different location. What code I have to add here. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot open the file or save in different location"? Is there any more observation?

Comment: Actually I can see the CSV file is selected in mentioned path directory in a dialog's box. And for code 1 : option is OPEN the CSV file , I click on the OPEN button the CSV file does not opens.  And for code 2: option is Save the CSV file , I browse a different location directory where I want to SAVE the selected CSV file , but not saving in the new location directory.

Comment: I used this "F:/python/bc_new_latest/bcForecasting.csv" because i want to make the specified csv to be selected in the dialog's box. As there are many other CSV files. But If i give the path "F:/python/bc_new_latest" and then select the required CSV and then click on the OPEN button still does not work.

Comment: Can you check the return value when it is not working? What is the filename set in that case?

Comment: If i print the filename , getting this : (u'F:/python/bc_new_latest/bcForecasting.csv', u'Excel (*.csv *.xls )')

Comment: That does not look good, right? You have tried to click on something else outside of the directory, yet you are getting the default? Please  try "F:/python/bc_new_latest/" for the path now. It might be a PyQt bug.

Comment: No suppose I clicked on another file outside the directory I am getting the filename : (u'C:/Documents and Settings/Dibyendu Dutta/Desktop/reference check form.xls', u'Excel (*.csv *.xls )')

Comment: Just please try with the previous suggestion. It should not matter, but I do not have any better idea. :-) It is simple to try out after all.

Comment: Sorry @LaszloPapp mentioning the path "F:/python/bc_new_latest/" , still not working :-) Can you please mark the question "need research effort" , that the expert QT/ python guys might have a look into it :)

Comment: I cannot, but does it work with native C++ Qt code?

Comment: I am not sure with native c++ QT code. As I am not used to c++ , i am trying in python

Answer (score 0):

These functions only allow the user to select files, they don't actually open or save the files.

In PySide, they return a tuple, so for example, saving the file would look like this:

```
fileName, selectedFilter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save",
                    "F:/python/bc_new_latest/bcForecasting.csv",
                    "Excel (*.csv *.xls )")
if fileName:
   with open(fileName, "w") as file:
       file.write(theCSVContent)
```